# Extract Column value into integer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a function that looks like this:

```
static Column getFormattedData(Column name, Column surname) {
        return concat(
                lit("NAME_")
                lpad(name,  greatest(length(name), lit(8)), "0"),
                lpad(surname, greatest(length(surname), lit(8)), "0"));
    }
```

Have issues at `lpad()` step, where `greatest()` returns a Column, while `lpad()` expects second parameter to be an `Integer`.

Is there way to extract the value of column into an integer form?

Alternatively, is there a better way to format the two columns/their values?

Edit:
As requested sample input:

e.g.,
`name: Joe` and `surname: Thomas`

Output: `NAME_00000JOE_00THOMAS`

(both first and last names are padded to 8 chars)

e.g.,
`name: Leonardo` and `surname: DaCaprio`

Output: `NAME_LEONARDO_DaCaprio`

(both names and surnames are >= 8 letters, hence no padding needed).

Comment: can you please add some input & expected output ?

Comment: Have added, as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------+--------+
|name    |surname |
+--------+--------+
|Joe     |Thomas  |
|Leonardo|DaCaprio|
+--------+--------+


scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

df
.select(
    concat(
        lit("NAME_"),
        lpad(upper($"name"), 8, "0"),
        lit("_"),
        lpad(upper($"surname"), 8, "0")
    ).as("output")
)
.show(false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+----------------------+
|output                |
+----------------------+
|NAME_00000JOE_00THOMAS|
|NAME_LEONARDO_DACAPRIO|
+----------------------+
```

Comment: So, you are suggesting `greatest()` is redundant here, is that right?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve same output without that

Comment: Thanks. However, the moot question is unresolved, is it possible to extract the `String` value out of `Column`?

Comment: why do you want extract string value out ? above solution is giving your expected output ?

Comment: Yes, it will. My question now is in general, if one has to.